# Node.js importing with ES6 import, specifically 'ytdl-core-discord'

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to use ytdl-core-discord in my discord bot.

In the doc I see:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
async function play(connection, url) {
  connection.play(await ytdl(url), { type: 'opus' });
}
```

Very simple, except I'm using the ES6 import and I can't make it work.
I get ytdl is not a function, I tried:

```
import {ytdl} from 'ytdl-core-discord'
```

and

```
import * as ytdl from 'ytdl-core-discord'
```

then ytdl.ytdl (URL) instead of ytdl

Also tried

```
import pkg from 'ytdl-core-discord';
const { ytdl } = pkg;
```

And I get the same ytdl is not a function error.

I checked on the repo and found that basically ytdl just wrap the function download from ytdl-core (I'm not 100%), so I tried:

```
import pkg from 'ytdl-core-discord';
const { download } = pkg;
```

But I get download is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import ytdl from "ytdl-core-discord";
```

What `node` version are you using? With `v14.15.1` and setting `type: "module"` in `package.json` working perfectly for me.